# How can we access sessionStorage in server side using MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, sessionstorage

i am saving some of the users insensitive data in the window.sessionStorage. this data is specific to the browsers tab, now i want to access the data which i have stored in the session storage from server side, how can i do that.

Comment: You can get the value using window.sessionStorage.getItem("key"); and pass it to some server side action using jQuery AJAX.

Comment: actually i am using angular4 in  my current project

Comment: $http({
   url: "/Home/SomeMethod", 
   method: "GET",
   params: {someKey: "userData"}
});

Comment: cant we access the sessionStorage from server side using some methods similar to how we access cookie from server side, something like this Request.Cookies["Currency"]

Comment: No, session storage is in client browser. It may not be possible to get it. maybe Activex could help, but works only on IE. Cookie is a different concept. Even if cookie disabled in client side, you can't access it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. `sessionStorage` is something that resides within the browser, on the client machine. ASP.NET MVC resides on your server. You can't simply 'pull' client-side browser data towards your server, the browser has to send it to you.

Using JavaScript, you can read whatever is in the session storage and then make an AJAX request to send it to ASP.NET MVC.

```
let sessionData = sessionStorage.yourData;
this.http.post('api/wherever', sessionData).subscribe(response => { ... });
```

Another option is to not store the data in the session storage but inside a cookie. Cookie data gets passed along with every HTTP request that goes out to your server. That way, the data will be immediately accessible in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Create an asp.net hidden field like this one,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$('#MainContent_hiddenFieldID').val(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionStorageVariableName'));", true);
```

then simply reference the hidden field on your serverside code.